# find keyword from url and replace from other word redirect rule iis

Tags: .net, url-rewriting, iis-7, web-config

I want to write one redirect rule in web.config
If URL found keyword then it should replace by some other word and word can be in any order

eg: http://www.exampleurl.com/analysis/ should go to 
http://www.exampleurl.com/data-and-analysis/

eg2: /xyz/analysis/ should go to 
/xyz/data-and-analysis/ where order of keyword (analysis) could be any.

url structure can be n level deep
.If  keyword "analysis" found in url at any place it should get replaced with keyword "data-and-analysis". please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This rule will do this redirects for you:

`http://www.exampleurl.com/analysis/` to `http://www.exampleurl.com/data-and-analysis/`

`http://www.exampleurl.com/xyz/analysis/` to `http://www.exampleurl.com/xyz/data-and-analysis/`

```
<rule name="data-and-analysis" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)analysis(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="data\-and\-analysis" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}data-and-analysis{R:2}" />
</rule>
```